# VBA Formula to cell that contains string and another formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to paste into a cell, using VBA, 3 connected VLOOKUP searches

```
TableIndex = 1
i = 1
ShiftColumn = 20
ShiftCount =  20
Cells(TableIndex, 43).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(R" & i & "C" & ShiftColumn & "R7C2:R" & ShiftCount & "C10,9),TEXT(VLOOKUP(R" & i & "C" & ShiftColumn & "R7C2:R" & ShiftCount & "C10,3),""hhmm""),TEXT(VLOOKUP(R" & i & "C" & ShiftColumn & "R7C2:R" & ShiftCount & "C10,4),""hhmm""))"
```

But it gives an 1004 error

Comment: Debug.Print the formula and try copying it into a cell - that will give you more info about what the problem might be.

Comment: You are missing the comma's between the lookup values and lookup ranges

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank you, it worked. For those who interested: `Cells(TableIndex, 43).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(R" & i & "C" & ShiftColumn - 1 & ",R7C2:R" & ShiftCount & "C10,9),"" "",TEXT(VLOOKUP(R" & i & "C" & ShiftColumn - 1 & ",R7C2:R" & ShiftCount & "C10,3),""hhmm""),""-"",TEXT(VLOOKUP(R" & i & "C" & ShiftColumn - 1 & ",R7C2:R" & ShiftCount & "C10,4),""hhmm""))"`